# how to solve this convert type error?

Tags: asp.net

How to solve this convert type error?

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List'
>   to 'System.Collections.Generic.List
>
> Error 2   Cannot implicitly convert type
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>`'
>   to
>   '`System.Collections.Generic.List<Product>`'  D:\Fortune\App_Code\BL\StoreController.cs   204 45  D:\Fortune\

```
public static List<Product> GetProductsByCategoryID(int productCategoryId )
{
    FortuneDataContext db = SiteController.GetNewFortuneDataContext();
    List<Product>  prods = (from p in db.Products
                        join pc in db.ProductCategories 
                        on p.ProductCategoryId equals pc.ProductCategoryId 
                        where pc.ParentProductCategoryId == productCategoryId
                        select new
                        {
                           p.ProductId,
                           p.ProductCategoryId,
                           pc.ParentProductCategoryId,               
                           ProductName = p.Name,
                           Category = pc.Name,
                           p.Price,
                           p.ProductYear
                           }).ToList();  
    return prods;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

change select to

```
select new Product {ProductId = p.ProductID
                       ...}).ToList();
```

or

```
   select p ...
```

if you want to extract all product fields

The error is that your list items are not products

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your ling query is not returning a product. It is returning an anonymous type because you are projecting a new type with the select new {}.

```
select new { ... }
```

You can either create a new type that has the category name in your object and change the method to return that or if you are using linq to sql you might be able to do something like product.category.name on the returned items.

```
 List<Product>  prods = (from p in db.Products
                           join pc in db.ProductCategories on p.ProductCategoryId equals pc.ProductCategoryId
                            where pc.ParentProductCategoryId == productCategoryId
                           select p).ToList<Product>();
```